# Error when Multidex Enabled

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I've recently had to enable multidex in my android studio project, this is built with imported module. It's doing well in the main project, but showing multidex problem in the project built with imported(from the main project) module.  I have followed [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) documentation to enable multidex. As the `application` tag is not overridden , so i've followed the method related. Now i'm getting this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\something\SalesDemo >Updated\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't >read [E:\something\SalesDemo >Updated\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't read [com] >(Can't read [smth] (Can't read [infolinkplus] (Can't read
>   [some.class] (Duplicate zip entry
>   [com/abc/def/some.class]))))))

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//noinspection GroovyMissingReturnStatement
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
  // buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.def.somethingotherthing"
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 16
    //noinspection OldTargetApi
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 16
    versionName "0.0.16"
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
//implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile project(':infolinkplus')
}
```

And the `manifest` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.abc.def.somethingotherthing">

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
   ...
  //ACTIVITIES AND META-TAGS
  ...
    </application>


</manifest>
```

After changes, i ran clean build and rebuilt but no result.
How can i overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you extend your `Application` class from `MultiDexApplication`?

Comment: add your android manifest file code.

Comment: No. I didn't and trying to avoid it. @Anton

Comment: If you do not want to extend MultiDexApplication and there is no Application class defined in your project then you can use . 
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >

Comment: Did i. @Vishalsharma

Comment: sometimes when enabling ProGuard eliminates the need for Multidex. Try it out

Comment: tried. the app runs but not properly. @pierre

Comment: Hi @FechangFuchang. Did you solve?

Comment: @PhanSinh Yes. But forgot how did it. Do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `Manifest` to provide `MultiDex`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

or if you have custom `Application` class, you have to extend it with `MultiDexApplication`

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Comment: Did it already. Added the manifest file in question. please check.

Answer (score 0):

> Duplicate zip entry
>   [com/abc/def/some.class]

In your project you must be having a class with name `some.class`  rename it to some thing else

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...
i hope you done this things..

```
        multiDexEnabled true
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

make class for application level..

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
}




        android:name="MyApplication" > // here define that class name that extends by MultiDexApplication
```

Comment: ` // here define that class name that extends by MultiDexApplication` - what do you mean by it?

Comment: if you follow code into define line then define your package name and class name that extends by MultiDexApplication in application tag.

Comment: I still cant understand what you say. Please explain editing your answer. Note that i  have no class that extends MultiDexApplication.

Comment: What if `MultiDexApplication` in `extends MultiDexApplication` appears red?

Comment: i define this MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication

Comment: I did it. but `MultiDexApplication` appears red here.

Comment: you add dependency into app level gradle file.

Comment: if you added then i hope studio import this line import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

Comment: Added dependency before. It worked after rebuild. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: but it didn't help still.

Comment: I think the module you have added compile project(':infolinkplus') is having the same class name which is in your main project. Please change the class name which is common in both and try to clean build and see if it helps you

Comment: No. This is not the problem.